# subst-if throws error work on tree in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, subst

Why am i getting this error:

> The value
>     (2 (2 (2 (2 (2) 2) 2) 2) 2)
>   is not of type
>     NUMBER
>   when binding SB-KERNEL::X
>      [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

when calling the `subst-if` with the follwoing test function:

```
(defun 2p (N) (= N 2))
(subst-if 3 #'2p '(2 (2 (2 (2 (2) 2) 2) 2) 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `equal` or `eql` (or any function that can compare arbitrary values, for your case `eql` being faster) in the `2p` function, as the function has to be able to receive any value inside the argument you're passing (the list with sublists). The `=` function is meant for numbers.

```
(defun 2p (N) (eql N 2))
```

The definition for `=`:

```
* (describe #'=)
#<FUNCTION =>
  [compiled function]


Lambda-list: (NUMBER &REST SB-KERNEL::MORE-NUMBERS)
Declared type: (FUNCTION (NUMBER &REST NUMBER)
                (VALUES BOOLEAN &OPTIONAL))
Derived type: (FUNCTION (NUMBER &REST T) (VALUES BOOLEAN &OPTIONAL))
Documentation:
  Return T if all of its arguments are numerically equal, NIL otherwise.
Known attributes: foldable, flushable, unsafely-flushable, movable, predicate, commutative
Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;NUMBERS.LISP
```